# Example of moving from MySQL to NoSQL?

Tags: mysql, nosql, migration

For a Facebook-like site, ie. which is write-intensive and delivers user-customized pages, I'd like to build a prototype to investigate whether the document-centric NoSQL architecture would be a good alternative to sharding and reduce the load on the single master (+ multiple slaves) that we currently use and is the bottleneck.

Does someone know of a good article that would give actual, simple examples of going from a relational layout in MySQL to a NoSQL layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check a real example of a working twitter simple clone

http://twissandra.com/

with source codes at http://github.com/ericflo/twissandra

Here's another good article explaining cassandra data model:

http://arin.me/blog/wtf-is-a-supercolumn-cassandra-data-model

Answer (score 0):

Many of the NoSQL type systems have details of migration, there are some video examples in here

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Articles

or try here

http://nosql-databases.org/

http://groups.google.com/group/nosql-discussion

Comment: Thanks. I haven't found an article that would show how a NoSQL architecture solves the issue of multiple DB write servers. I'll see if I can find something to figure it out.